# How to un-shuffle data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shuffle

it may exist a method to coming back from the function `shuffle` from `sklearn.utils`? 
I explain better my problem: I use the `shuffle` function to randomize the rows of two matrices:

`A_s, B_s = shuffle(A, B, random_state = 1)`

Next I use both matrices `A_s`, `B_s` in some operation and I obtain an other matrix `C_s` with the same dimension: e.g. `C_s = f(A_s, B_s)`. How to come back to the original order of `C` as `A` and `B`?

I'm thinking something similar to `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler((0,+1))` and after I come back using `sklearn.inverse_transform()`.

Comment: `f` is just a simple function, e.g., a sum.
So, sorry if I persist stressing you, how I can do my personal shuffle function? I think something like this:

`for i in range(len(A)):
     A_s[i,:] = np.random(A[i,:])
     B_s[i,:] = np.random(B[i,:])
`
but how can I keep track on the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not necessarily be possible, depending on your choice of `f`.  If `f` is invertible, and you keep track of the manner in which the rows were shuffled, it will be possible, if not efficient.  The sklearn.utils shuffle method does NOT "keep track" of the manner in which the matrix was shuffled.  You may want to roll your own.  To generate a random shuffle, generate a random permutation of `range(len(A))`, then iteratively swap the rows in that order.  To retrieve the original matrices, you can just reverse the permutation.  This would allow you to recover C for certain choices of `f` (e.g. matrix addition)

(EDIT, OP requested additional info)

This works for me, but there's probably a more efficient way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

def shuffle(A,axis=0,permutation=None):
    A = np.swapaxes(A,0,axis)
    if permutation is None:
        permutation = np.random.permutation(len(A))
    temp = np.copy(A[permutation[0]])
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        A[permutation[i]] = A[permutation[i+1]]
    A[permutation[-1]] = temp
    A = np.swapaxes(A,0,axis)
    return A, permutation

A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
print A
B, p = shuffle(A) #NOTE: shuffle is in place, so A is the same object as B!!!!
print "shuffle A"
print B
D, _ = shuffle(B,permutation=p[::-1])
print "unshuffle B to get A"
print D

B = np.copy(B)
C = A+B
print "A+B"
print C

A_s, p = shuffle(A)
B_s, _ = shuffle(B, permutation = p)
C_s = A_s + B_s

print "shuffle A and B, then add"
print C_s

print "unshuffle that to get the original sum"
CC, _ = shuffle(C_s, permutation=p[::-1])
print CC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want to know how to do not change the initial matrix, in your example `A`. There exist a method to do like this?

Comment: Just add the line `A=np.copy(A)` at the very top of the function

Comment: You mean just after the row `A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])`? Because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np


def shuffle(x):
    x_s = x.copy()
    x_s.insert(0, x_s.pop())
    return x_s


def unshuffle(x, shuffle):
    shuffled_ind = shuffle(list(range(len(x))))
    rev_shuffled_ind = np.argsort(shuffled_ind)
    x_unshuffled = np.array(x)[rev_shuffled_ind].tolist()
    return x_unshuffled


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
x_s = shuffle(x)
print(x_s)
x_r = unshuffle(x_s, shuffle)
print(x_r)
```

A late answer here.

In reality, you have your own shuffle() function.

The idea is to make a sequence shuffled, and use np.argsoft() to get the index for unshuffling.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to reset or unshuffle:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**NB**: This will only reorganize the index numbers, not the entire rows.